# Асинхронный цикл JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив элементов. Хочу пройтись по ним и подсветить их на 300ms. Делаю примерно вот так:

```
for (let item of array){
  item.classList.add('active')
  setTimeout( () => {
    item.classList.remove('active')
    }, 300)
}
```

Но все происходит моментально. Перепробовал промисы, async че-то не получается. Подскажите как можно оформить?

Comment: Так переход нужно задерживать а вы задерживаете подсветку. Так и получается что каждый моментально подсвечивается и обратно. Вам нужно итеративно чтоб каждый вызывал следующий когда подсветка закончится

Comment: Перебирайте по индексам или сохраняйте предыдущий в переменную.

Comment: можно вместо `300` выставить разные значения от итерации